# bootstrap remove space between divs in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a shape like this
[image]

And here's my code:

```
<section style="background-color: red;">
    <div>
       <div class="row justify-content-center px-4 d-flex flex-column">
           <div class="col-lg-4 text-center py-5 rounded" style="background: white">
               <p>Let's work together!</p>
               <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" style="color: #3E7DC0; border-radius: 8px;">
              <span style="font-weight: 900;"><mdicon name="whatsapp"/> Contact us now!</a><br>
           </div>
           <div class="down-triangle align-self-center p-0"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="image.png">
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

and here's my CSS for the small triangle

```
.down-triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid white; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

With that code, here's a picture of what I got
[image]

My question is, how do I remove the spacing between those two divs? I've tried margin bottom and padding bottom but it doesn't work. Thank you so much.

Comment: hi, could you provide your full code

Comment: @Themodmin done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `relative` for your position that will allow you to control of the location relatively with `top` like this :

```
.down-triangle {
top: -20px;
position: relative;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 40px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
border-right:40px solid white; 
border-radius: 4px;
transform: rotate(270deg);}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked! thank you so much!! i was going to try this method but i didn't know if this was the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a padding property in your css file. It should look like this:

```
.down-triangle {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 40px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
   border-right:40px solid white; 
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 0
   transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could always try setting the padding of the square to 0, as that could be the problem, or using negative margins.

Comment: thank you! really appreaciate your help!